# fail to start mysql(mariadb)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i have been spending hours figuring out problems in connection mysql to use mariadb eventually. here's a situation.

situation:

1.i use macbook, and i am not that familiar with computer programming.
i tried to connect java eclipse and mariadb. so i looked it up online.
and at the same time, i opened up terminal and started my mysql using

```
mysql.server start
```

and it worked. and i was supposed to download mariaddb.2.2 jar something to connect it with eclipse, but i mistakenly downloaded "mariadb-10.2.12-osx10.13-x86_64.pkg" and installed it. and i also typed

```
mysql.server stop
```

and all that kind of things. lots and lots of things so that i can`t even remember
after i found out i downloaded the wrong things, i felt like this is way beyond my skills, so i jumped back to play with mariadb.

i opened up terminal and typed

```
mysql.server start
```

and termial keeps showing me this until now

```
.180322 00:04:47 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/sinjinhos-MacBook-Air-146.local.err'.
180322 00:04:47 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
. ERROR!
```

i still think that this tragedy started beacause i installed mariadb again...
i literally tried everything and still couldn`t figure it out.
please help me!!

Comment: "mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/sinjinhos-MacBook-Air-146.local.err'"... What is in that file?

Comment: i wish i could answer that

Comment: Nobody can help if you can't provide errors. Run this to view the end of the file: `tail /usr/local/var/mysql/sinjinhos-MacBook-Air-146.local.err`

Comment: 2018-03-22  0:36:36 140736284734272 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 48: Address already in use
2018-03-22  0:36:36 140736284734272 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2018-03-22  0:36:36 140736284734272 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: my bad, still don`t get used to this website. so i run it and it showed me this messages.

Answer (score 2):

From your initial post you can see that mariadb is logging the following file.

> 180322 00:04:47 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/sinjinhos-MacBook-Air-146.local.err'

Inside that file you found the following error.

> 2018-03-22 0:36:36 140736284734272 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 48: Address already in use 2018-03-22 0:36:36 140736284734272 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ? 2018-03-22 0:36:36 140736284734272 [ERROR] Aborting

The key part of the error is `Address already in use`. Everything running on your computer that listens for connections (like a database or a web server) will listen on a specific port. MySQL (and therefore MariaDB) listens on port `3306` by default. The important part is that *you can't have multiple applications listening on the same port*!

So where do you go from here? I suspect you still have MySQL running on your laptop, and once you stop it you will be able to start up a new instance.

To check if MySQL is running you can use the following command:

`ps -ef | grep mysql`

If anything shows here then it is running, and you should stop the service. How you do this will vary depending on how you installed it - try `mysql.server stop` first and run the above command again. If it is still running and you can't figure it out then you can `kill` the service. This is not recommended and cause MySQL data corruption - although if you have no data there then you should be OK.

Example output of `ps -ef`. Yours should show MySQL near the end, and the second column shows the process ID which you can use to kill the process.

```
    PID
    \/
0  9504  9491   0  3:44pm ttys007    0:00.00 ps -ef`
```

So I would use:

```
kill 9504
```

You should then be able to start the service again.

```
mysql.server start
```

Comment: first of all, thank you so much. here's what i got after following your guidance. so i typed "ps -ef | grep mysql", then i have the following

Comment: 74    74     1   0 11:36PM ??         0:01.64 /usr/local/mariadb/server/bin/mariadbd --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mariadb/server --log-basename=mariadb --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mariadb/server/lib/plugin
  501 36856 36626   0  1:02AM ttys001    0:00.01 grep mysql
sinjinhos-MacBook-Air-146:~ JinhoShin$

Comment: and when i typed <mysql.server stop>,  ERROR! MariaDB server PID file could not be found! => this message shows up

Comment: So you need `kill 74`

Comment: so i tried to kill that PID, which i assume it's 74 in my case, so i typed kill 74 and it says "Operation not permitted"

Comment: `sudo kill 74`, enter your password

Comment: I recommend you take a look at a tutorial for the command line. Maybe something [like this](https://github.com/fonnesbeck/Bios6301/wiki/Mac-OS-X-Command-Line-Tutorial).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167284/discussion-between-jim-wright-and-jjjjjin).